# Как наладить cmake, чтоб он автоматически генерил c++ файлы из grpc proto файлов?

Tags: c++, cmake, google-protobuf, grpc

У меня есть cmake, который автоматически генерит прото файлы в с++ файлы. Но что мне нужно добавить в этот файл, чтоб файлы, использующие grpc тоже генерились ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project(protobuf_test4)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS person.proto)
add_executable(protobuf_test4 main.cpp ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(protobuf_test4 ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

*дополнение

Попробовал следующий способ

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(gRPC_test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set(FILES
        test.pb.h
        test.pb.cc
        test.grpc.pb.h
        test.grpc.pb.cc
        )
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${FILES}
        COMMAND protobuf::protoc
        ARGS "--proto_path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        "--cpp_out=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.proto
        COMMAND protobuf::protoc
        ARGS "--proto_path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        "--grpc_out=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
        "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>"
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.proto
        DEPENDS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.proto
)
add_executable(gRPC_test main.cpp test.pb.cc test.grpc.pb.cc  test.grpc.pb.h test.pb.h)
target_link_libraries(gRPC_test ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES} gRPC::grpc++)
```

Но теперь компилятор видит ошибки в скомпилированном файле. Ошибки от того что не найдены функции. Похоже какая то библиотека не подтянулась. В чем может быть дело?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::ClearToEmpty()’
```

Comment: У меня через `add_custom_command` реализованно и работает. Возможно дело в стандарте языка, вы используете 17 и 20, а вот под какой стандарт компилит protoc? Попробуйте 14 поставить. И еще: вы grpc какой берете? из исходников или из пакета в репозитории? Если из репозитория то думаю лучше взять из иходником. У меня с тем который в репозитории проблемы были, правда не на этапе компиляции. И попробуйте выставить также `set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)` файлы то он все таки сишные генерирует

Comment: @Rikitikitavi, беру из исходников, проблемы в не grpc файле, он компилился через protobuf_generate_cpp и с 20 стандартом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно примерно так сделать:

```
 set(FILES
     Service.pb.h
     Service.pb.cc
     Service.grpc.pb.h
     Service.grpc.pb.cc
   )     


 add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT ${FILES}
      COMMAND protobuf::protoc
      ARGS "--proto_path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
           "--cpp_out=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProtoFile.proto
      COMMAND protobuf::protoc
      ARGS "--proto_path=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
           "--grpc_out=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
           "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>"
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProtoFile.proto
      DEPENDS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ProtoFile.proto
 )
```

Comment: Использовал этот способ, файлы скомпилились, но почему то в скомпелированном файле ошибка, при компиляции через cpp generate такого нет. Оставлю информацию в правке.